# Criar um método set para variáveis diferentes

Tags: java, método, getters-setters

Estou querendo criar um *setter* para um objeto `Character`, onde ele modificará os atributos `String name`, `int intellect`, `int strength` e `int stamina`, mas qual é o melhor método para se fazer isso?

```
public class Character {

    private String name;
    private int intellect;
    private int strength;
    private int stamina;

    public void setAttribute( ??? ) {

    } // fim do método setAttribute
} // fim da classe Character
```

Comment: Melhor em que sentido? Não está claro qual é a sua dúvida. Seria uma questão de estilo de codificação, ou talvez como criar uma boa API pros métodos chamadores, etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existem algumas formas, e que seguem o padrão de Programação Orientada a Objeto e são:

1 - Padrão com Get/Set:

```
public class Character 
{       
    private String name;
    private int intellect;
    private int strength;
    private int stamina;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getIntellect() {
        return intellect;
    }
    public void setIntellect(int intellect) {
        this.intellect = intellect;
    }
    public int getStrength() {
        return strength;
    }
    public void setStrength(int strength) {
        this.strength = strength;
    }
    public int getStamina() {
        return stamina;
    }
    public void setStamina(int stamina) {
        this.stamina = stamina;
    }
}
```

2 - Padrão com Get/Set + Construtor:

```
public class Character 
{       
    public Character(){ }
    public Character(String name, int intellect, int strength, int stamina){ 
        this.name = name;
        this.intellect = intellect;
        this.strength = strength;
        this.stamina = stamina;
    }
    private String name;
    private int intellect;
    private int strength;
    private int stamina;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getIntellect() {
        return intellect;
    }
    public void setIntellect(int intellect) {
        this.intellect = intellect;
    }
    public int getStrength() {
        return strength;
    }
    public void setStrength(int strength) {
        this.strength = strength;
    }
    public int getStamina() {
        return stamina;
    }
    public void setStamina(int stamina) {
        this.stamina = stamina;
    }
}
```

3 - Padrão com Get/Set + Construtor + Interface Fluente

```
public class Character {
    public Character() { }
    public Character(String name, int intellect, int strength, int stamina){ 
        this.name = name;
        this.intellect = intellect;
        this.strength = strength;
        this.stamina = stamina;
    }
    private String name;
    private int intellect;
    private int strength;
    private int stamina;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public Character setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
    public int getIntellect() {
        return intellect;
    }
    public Character setIntellect(int intellect) {
        this.intellect = intellect;
        return this;
    }
    public int getStrength() {
        return strength;
    }
    public Character setStrength(int strength) {
        this.strength = strength;
        return this;
    }
    public int getStamina() {
        return stamina;
    }
    public Character setStamina(int stamina) {
        this.stamina = stamina;
        return this;
    }
}
```

---

Como utilizar:

Seguindo o 3 que contém todos os exemplos segue abaixo o código:

**Interface Fluent:**

```
Character ca1 = new Character();
        ca1
            .setName("Nome 1")            
            .setIntellect(1)
            .setStrength(2)
            .setStamina(3);
```

---

**Pelo Construtor:**

```
Character ca2 = new Character("Nome 1", 1, 2, 3);
```

---

**Forma Tradicional:**

```
Character ca3 = new Character();
ca3.setName("Nome 1");            
ca3.setIntellect(1);
ca3.setStrength(2);
ca3.setStamina(3);
```

Comment: Obrigado! não cheguei a ver ainda **Interface Fluent**, vou pesquisar, só vi a interface de implementação por enquanto, mas não entendi muito bem quando você se diz `Code.` em seus exemplos.

Comment: @BrunoNeuman o Code é o pacote, vou retirar para ficar mais legível, me desculpe !!!

Comment: ahh entendi =P assim sim como diria o Chaves :)

Comment: Aproveitando, não existe uma forma de criar um *setter* universal para todas as variáveis, em que eu declarasse constantes para referenciar as variáveis do método *setter*?

Comment: Com Reflection você poderia conseguir sim, mas, sinceramente seria um gambiarra, quanto mais fino é sua classe melhor é sua performace e Padrão em POO ajuda demais em manutenção, ... o mais correto são essas maneiras e o padrões empregados pela POO!

Comment: Se puder, da uma olhada, isso seria PURA gambiarra ou economia de código?
http://pastebin.com/xP1inyY3

Comment: @BrunoNeuman na minha experiência como programadora diz que é funcional, mas, fora do padrão e para mim gambiarra. Desculpa em dar minha opinião ...

Comment: Eu QUERO sua opinião hahah, estou iniciando em programação e gostaria de evitar ao máximo esses meios "funcionais" então me vale muito sua opinião :) Obrigado mesmo pela sua atenção!

Comment: @BrunoNeuman já que você quer opiniões, eu diria que o que você fez é desnecessário: `myChar.setAttribute( myChar.STAMINA, 45 );` por exemplo. Você gasta muito tempo para fazer algo que vai tornar seu código mais complexo e o resultado final é o mesmo, atribuir um valor a um atributo privado do objeto. Existem inúmeros bom motivos para você não fazer assim, um deles é o JavaBean Standard, que uma das coisas que tenta padronizar são os getters and setters para facilitar a comunicação entre desenvolvedores, outro motivo é que as IDEs já geram getters and setters automaticamente para você.

Comment: @Maria o que seria essa "Interface Fluent"? É algo que é comumente praticado e possui esse nome? Estou perguntando apenas por curiosidade, pois nunca ouvi falar.

Comment: @Math é um padrão de projeto e é utilizado sim em todas as linguagens orientadas a objeto, é um facilitador ao meu ver na hora da digitação e você pode ver esse padrão e muito quando se utiliza expressões para montar uma cadeia de configurações e no final executa. Na verdade eles falam "builder" com características de "interface fluent", mas, significa a mesma coisa. Nesse link: http://pt.slideshare.net/kindblad/the-fluent-interface-pattern pode ficar mais claro para você! No exemplo o 1 e 2 não muda muito mas, o três os `set` te uma diferença, porque, aponta para a classe repare esse item.

Comment: Putz, sempre gostei de usar esse padrão `Fluent` mas nunca sabia o nome, muito bom ter citado esse padrão. +1

Answer (score 3):

Você gostaria de criar só um método para fazer o set das 4 variáveis? Se sim, acho que a melhor maneira seria essa aqui:

```
public class character {

    private String name;
    private int intellect;
    private int strength;
    private int stamina;

    public void setAttribute(String name, int intellect, int strenght, int stamina) {
         this.name = name;
         this.intellect = intellect;
         this.strength = strenght;
         this.stamina = stamina;
    }
}
```

Qualquer outra dúvida pode perguntar!

Comment: Sim, gostaria de criar um unico método *setter* para que ele possa ser utilizado para pelo menos as 3 variáveis do tipo int, onde eu pudesse "saber" quando chamasse o método *setter* informar para quem eu gostaria de atribuir o valor, para variável intellect, para strength ou para stamina